# Convert Datetime in array for PHP

Tags: php, arrays, odbc

uploaded csv file with date in it, failed.
uploaded csv file w/o date, data save in db but there's another error:- 
No tuples available at this result index....

SQL state 22008: I think because it cannot read my date format.
my current format in csv is like this:- 04/02/2017..

is there any way to convert date format in array?

i've tried to convert using "date('d/m/Y',strtotime($dateRecorded))" format inside the array but its not working.

```
include('../db_conn.php');
  $output = '';  
  $allowed_ext = array("csv");  
  $extension = end(explode(".", $_FILES["employee_file"]["name"]));  
  if(in_array($extension, $allowed_ext))  
  {  
       $file_data = fopen($_FILES["employee_file"]["tmp_name"], 'r');  
       fgetcsv($file_data);  
       while($row = fgetcsv($file_data))  
       {  
           $accnum = addslashes($row[0]);  
           $dedate = addslashes($row[1]); //deposit date  
           $transcode = addslashes($row[2]);  
           $amount = addslashes($row[3]);  
           $reffno = addslashes($row[4]);  
           $remarks = addslashes($row[5]);      
  $query = odbc_exec("INSERT INTO accdetails VALUES(   '0','','".$accnum."','".$dedate."','".$transcode."','".$amount."','".$reffno."','".$remarks."','','','','','')"); 
            $result = odbc_fetch_array($query);
```

im getting this error:-

SQL error: [Informix][Informix ODBC Driver][Informix]Non-numeric character in datetime or interval., SQL state 22008

---

i've checked my query for insert, but i cannot see any multiple result has been produced is it because of my while loop?

previously i used odbc_fetch_array... but when i googled it, they said to replace it with odbc_next_result. but done it but same thing happened.

```
  $select2 = odbc_exec("SELECT * FROM accdetails ORDER BY spiid ASC");  
       $result2 = odbc_fetch_array($select2);  
       $output .= '  
            <table class="table table-bordered">  
                 <tr>  
                           <th>ID</th>  
                           <th>File Name</th>  
                           <th>Acc No</th>  
                           <th>Depo Date </th>
                           <th>Trans Code</th>  
                           <th>Amount</th>  
                           <th>Reff No</th>  
                           <th>Remarks</th> 
                 </tr>  
                    ';  
       while($row =  odbc_next_result($result2))  
       {  
            $output .= '  
                    <tr>  
                           <td>'.$row["spiid"].'</td>  
                           <td>'. $row["spifilename"].'</td>  
                           <td>'.$row["spiaccountno"].'</td>  
                           <td>'.$row["spidepositdate"].'</td>                                
                           <td>'.$row["spitranscode"].'</td>  
                           <td>'. $row["spiamount"].'</td>  
                           <td>'.$row["spireferenceno"].'</td>  
                           <td>'.$row["spiremarks"].'</td>
                 </tr>  
            ';  
       }  
       $output .= '</table>';  
       echo $output;  
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL date should be YYYY-mm-dd format.

so you need to change

```
$dedate = addslashes($row[1]);
```

by

```
$dedate = date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s', $row[1] );
```

Hope you're getting date in `$row[1]`

Comment: yes, got it! thank you so much, but do you know why i get another error as i mention there?

**No tuples available at this result index

Comment: There might be more than one result set. Could you check your insert query? columns seems missing after table name.

Comment: i've edit my question with the insert query. can you pls check wht's wrong with it? is it because of my while loop?

Comment: I guess this line $result = odbc_fetch_array($query); the $query is for INSERT and you're fetching data.